# Skipping failed external commands before running app in Android Studio's run config

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

I want to perform a few cleaning tasks before running my app on Avd, using Android Studio.
I created a configuration that calls adb shell commands like **uninstall** or **rm -r** before installing app on emulator.

The problem is that if the app is already uninstalled, then the entire config fails, and the app is not installed.

Is there a way to continue even when previous commands failed?

Comment: Did you add those tasks in "Before launch" section of your run configuration?

Comment: yes, I did add them as external task there.

Comment: Currently it's not possible. Feel free to create feature request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Thanks for the info. Why not write it as an answer to the question?

Comment: For me it doesn't look like an answer with some soluion or workaround :)